# Exception handling in Java - Keep executing until user enters four valid employee IDs

Tags: java, exception

What's wrong with this code:

DebugTwelve4.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
throw(new FixDebugEmployeeIDException("Number too high " + emps[x]));
^
symbol:   class FixDebugEmployeeIDException
location: class DebugTwelve4
DebugTwelve4.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
catch(FixDebugEmployeeIDException error)
^
symbol:   class FixDebugEmployeeIDException
location: class DebugTwelve4
2 errors
Error: Could not find or load main class DebugTwelve4

```
DebugEmployeeIDException.java:

public class DebugEmployeeIDException extends Exception
{
   public DebugEmployeeIDException()
   {
      super("Debug employee exception");
   }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------
DebugTwelve4.java:

// An employee ID can't be more than 999
// Keep executing until user enters four valid employee IDs
// This program throws a FixDebugEmployeeIDException
import java.util.*;
public class DebugTwelve4
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String inStr, outString = "";
      final int MAX = 999;
      int[] emps = new int[4];
      int x;
      try
      {
      for(x = 0; x < emps.length; ++x)
      {
        System.out.println("Enter employee ID number");
         inStr = input.next();
         throw(new NumberFormatException("Number format exception"));
         {
            emps[x] = Integer.parseInt(inStr);
            if(emps[x] > MAX)
            {
               throw(new FixDebugEmployeeIDException("Number too high " + emps[x]));
            }
         }
      }
         
      }
      catch(NumberFormatException error)
         {  
            --x;
            System.out.println(inStr + "\nNonnumeric ID");
         }
         catch(FixDebugEmployeeIDException error)
         {  
        --x;
        System.out.println("FixDebugEmployeeIDException");
         }

      for(x = 0; x < emps.length; ++x);
      {
         outString = outString + emps[x] + " ";
      }
      System.out.println("Four valid IDS are: " + outString);    
   }
}
```

Comment: try throw new FixDebugEmployeeIDException("Number too high " + emps[x]);

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: why are you throwing a NumberFormatException?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing all your codes in one method (main method), there is actually no need to throw any exceptions.

Typically, you throw an exception when you are chaining method calls and you do not want to handle the error there and then -> you throw it and propagate it back to the caller for caller to handle.

In the context of your question, you can just a simple if/else check within the loop to ensure that the input is never more than 999.

```
int[] employeeIds = new int[4]
final int _MAX_ = 999;

for (int i = 0 ; i < employeeIds.length; i++) {
  int input = sc.nextInt();
  if (input > _MAX_) {
    System.out.println("Invalid ID, please try again!");
    i--; // when invalid input, this ensures that the index stays the same
    continue;
  } else {
    employeeIds[i] = input;
  }
}

// loop through employeeIds and print your output
```

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me.

```
public class DebugEmployeeIDException extends Exception
{
    public DebugEmployeeIDException()
    {
        super("Debug employee exception");
    }
    public DebugEmployeeIDException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}


import java.util.*;
public class DebugTwelve4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inStr="", outString = "";
        final int MAX = 999;
        int[] emps = new int[4];
        int x=0;
        try
        {
            for(x = 0; x < emps.length; ++x)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter employee ID number");
                inStr = input.next();
                emps[x] = Integer.parseInt(inStr);
                if(emps[x] > MAX)
                {
                    throw new DebugEmployeeIDException("Number too high " + emps[x]);
                }
            }

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException error)
        {  
            --x;
            System.out.println(inStr + "\nNonnumeric ID");
        }
        catch(DebugEmployeeIDException error)
        {  
            --x;
            System.out.println("FixDebugEmployeeIDException");
        }


        for(x = 0; x < emps.length;x++)
        {
            outString = outString + emps[x] + " ";
        }
        System.out.println("Four valid IDS are: " + outString);    
    }
}
```